# rollup summary fields filter criteria

Tags: roll-up-summary

I am trying to create a rollup summary field on master object.
I can create it fine.But when i try to impose a filter on child records for rolling up,
i cannot see all fields listed there.Say for example in my child object,there is a lookup relationship to Opportunity and want to rollup those records whose opportunity__c is not null.I cannot even see the field list.
I do have another field for contact lookup and ie listed.

Is there a particular criteria for fields coming there?

Comment: Hmm.  I tried adding a lookup to Contact on my detail record within a M-D relationship and the contact is NOT available for use in a RSF filter. You might want to elaborate more (screen shot). And I presume you are talking about OOB SFDC RSF fields, not a 3rd party package

Answer (score 1):

The [About Roll-Up Summary Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US) documentation says:

> Long text area, multi-select picklist, Description, system fields like
>   Last Activity, cross-object formula fields, and lookup fields (such as
>   the Product Code field) cannot be used in the field column of roll-up
>   summary filters.

Comment: But then how come contact is available

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the lookup field in a filter on a rollup summary field you need to change a setting on the lookup field.

For "What to do if the lookup record is deleted?" you must select "Don't allow deletion of the lookup record that's part of a lookup relationship."

On your child object, change this setting on your Opportunity lookup and when you go back to your rollup summary field you will see your Opportunity lookup in the list of fields to choose in a filter.  I don't know if this helps you over a year later, but maybe if someone else with this problem stumbles on this (like I did!) it will save them some aggravation.